# Cordova for write/read files on android?

Tags: angular11

I want to read files or write files in Android file system. My project is developed in Angular11 and converting it to APK using Cordova.

Answer (score 0):

To read and write files in Cordova (for Android, iOS, or others), use the standard plugin `cordova-plugin-file`.  To install it, run this from your cordova project directory:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
```

For a list of which directories you can read or write in on Android, see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/11.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#android-file-system-layout

Note that the docs for this at Cordova give examples but don't always describe the API in detail.  The plugin is based on the old W3C standard for the File API, where you can find the complete details if you need them:  https://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/file-dir-sys.html

Good luck!